# GIMP - Image - How to keep image quality when reduce image size?

Tags: scale, resolution, gimp, image-quality

I have a image size 300x300mm resolution 72pixel/in.
I want resize it to 120x120mm but keep the quality (by increase resolution?).

First test, I increase its resolution to 180pixel/in then scale it to 120x120 >> image still degrade.

Second test, I increase its resolution to 180pixel/in then scale it to 150x150 >> image still degrade.

Can you help me out? Thanks,

Comment: Look here: https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-image-scale.html

Comment: So we can not keep the quality even if we increase its resolution?

Comment: It's digital, must be somthing we can do?

Comment: If I convert it to TIFF then resize. Does it work? Or may be the conversion degrade the image?

Comment: You need to have TIFF at start. JPEG has limited information, it will not help you even you will convert it to TIFF. Look at my answer below, that's the only way (Smart Sharpening).

Comment: What about PNG? Can I convert it to TIFF and keep its quality? Thank you so much :)

Comment: the same story, you cannot ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to keep quality if you will resize JPEG or PNG, because the way how the algorithms works. Only if you will work on raw or tiff files, you can change your image size without problems. Using links below you can make it less blurry.

Look here:
https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Smart_Sharpening/ and https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-image-scale.html

More on JPEG algorithm:

http://www.whydomath.org/node/wavlets/basicjpg.html

http://www.ams.org/samplings/feature-column/fcarc-image-compression

Comment: I guess you can still enhance the quality of the image, using some website that supports AI. For example, the case with google photos, it corrects picture quality after it has been taken.